# Data Extraction over multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm totally new to VBA and I'm trying to script an excel module to extract a specific section on each sheet of a workbook and format them and output together to 1 sheet on a new workbook.

So far I have this;

```
Public Sub extractCol()

    ' Find FF&E Section, Add 3 rows and Identify relevant columns.

    Dim rFind As Range

    With Range("A:A")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:="FF&E", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, 
        SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then

            NumRange = rFind.Row + 3 ' Find FF&E line and add three
            CRange = "C" & NumRange & ":" & "C" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 
            Lines in Column C
            ERange = "E" & NumRange & ":" & "E" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 
            Lines in Column E
            KRange = "K" & NumRange & ":" & "K" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 
            Lines in Column K
            MRange = "M" & NumRange & ":" & "M" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 
            Lines in Column M


            Set range1 = Union(Range(CRange), Range(ERange), Range(KRange), 
            Range(MRange)) ' Combine individual column ranges in to one selection
            range1.Copy ' Copy new combined range

            Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add ' Open new Workbook
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste to new Workbook

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

This is great as it extracts the bits that I wan't correctly but it only does the current sheet. How do I loop this to do all sheets?

Secondly I would like to paste all the results to the same sheet under one another?

And finally I have the below script that extracts the sheet name and formats it. Ideally I would like to add a column to the output above which would display this data depending on which sheet it came from.

```
Function FindRoom()

    shtName = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim arr() As String
    arr = VBA.Split(shtName, " ")

    xCount = UBound(arr)
    If xCount < 1 Then
        FindRoom = ""
    Else
        FindRoom = arr(xCount)
    End If
End Function
```

Sorry, I know this is not a simple one answer question but any help would be grateful even if it's just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: There are many code examples of how to loop through sheets. A For-Next loop is standard and you just need to reference a worksheet variable. Have you tried this avenue and got stuck? Do you mean you want all the results in the new workbook?

Comment: I did come across this but I got stuck as I couldn't get it to work. I would like it to loop through each sheet and add the results to a new workbook sheet. My assumption is that I need the loop to happen but instead of just making a new workbook every time it just finds the last row and adds to the first workbook it set up.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? The problem with your FindRoom function is that it returns an empty string in some cases?

Comment: the sheet names are always formatted the same when we receive the document. For example "General room 0.16" or "Seminar room 1.10" etc. The bit that concerns us is the room reference number ie 0.16 which is always at the end of the description. The FindRoom script I put together from my understanding extracts that. Is there a reason why it might come back blank?

Comment: Only that there is provision for it in the UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I've added a worksheet variable `ws`. This puts the sheet name in column A of the new workbook, and the data in col B onwards. I have also added declarations for all the variables.

```
Public Sub extractCol()

'Find FF&E Section, Add 3 rows and Identify relevant columns.

Dim rFind As Range, CRange As String, ERange As String, KRange As String, MRange As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim NumRange As Long

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add ' Open new Workbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Set rFind = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="FF&E", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            NumRange = rFind.Row + 3 ' Find FF&E line and add three
            CRange = "C" & NumRange & ":" & "C" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column C
            ERange = "E" & NumRange & ":" & "E" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column E
            KRange = "K" & NumRange & ":" & "K" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column K
            MRange = "M" & NumRange & ":" & "M" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column M

            Set range1 = Union(.Range(CRange), .Range(ERange), .Range(KRange), .Range(MRange)) ' Combine individual column ranges in to one selection
            range1.Copy ' Copy new combined range
            NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste to new Workbook
            NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(range1.Rows.Count).Value = FindRoom(ws)
        End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub

Function FindRoom(ws As Worksheet)

    shtName = ws.Name

    Dim arr() As String
    arr = VBA.Split(shtName, " ")

    xCount = UBound(arr)
    If xCount < 1 Then
        FindRoom = ""
    Else
        FindRoom = arr(xCount)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It's failing because it can't run the FindRoom function I think. Once I replace the FindRoom part with just a string it works fine. Where do I have to put the FindRoom function in the script so I can call it here? Thanks for the help. The loop is definitely working which gives me hope!

Comment: My mistake - I updated the function to add a parameter but forgot to include the amended code. Try it now.

Comment: Just had another go at it. It was my mistake. Your code is perfect. Thank you so much for the help. Works a treat.